# How to turn it an element of a list to a string?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have lists like this in a column of a data frame:

```
list1 = [[Petitioner Jae Lee,his,he],[]]

list2 = [[lee],[federal officials]]

list3 = [[],[lawyer]]
```

But I want to turn into

```
list1 = ['Petitioner Jae Lee' , 'his','he']
list2 = ['lee' , 'federal officials']]
list3 = ['lawyer']
```

and I want to do it for a column in a data frame.  How can I do it?

Comment: How are you reading in that data? Current Pandas would most likely default to bringing that in as a string already. Before you fix what shouldn't be an issue, you may want to go back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [['Petitioner Jae Lee','his','he'],[]]
list2 = [['lee'],['federal officials']]
list3 = [[],['lawyer']]

flat_list1 = [item for sublist in list1 for item in sublist]
flat_list2 = [item for sublist in list2 for item in sublist]
flat_list3 = [item for sublist in list3 for item in sublist]

print(flat_list1)
print(flat_list2)
print(flat_list3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=series%20map#pandas.Series.map) to apply the logic row-wise.

To concatenate the sublists into a single list you can use the built-in `sum` function

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda list_i : sum(list_i, []))
```

A better alternative is to unpack the sublists and pass them to [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
import itertools as it 
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda list_i : list(it.chain(*list_i)))
```

Or use a nested list comprehension

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda list_i : [string for sublist in list_i for string in sublist])
```